# in Hyperledger fabric composer, error when adding asset

Tags: angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've followed the instructions in the following link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/applications/genapp.html and was able to generate an angular application based on the banana file (carauction-network.bna) I've deployed.

However, when I tried adding asset using the generated angular application, it was not responding and the composer rest server stopped.

Please see the error details below from npm-debug.log file.

```
10 verbose lifecycle angular-app@0.0.0~app: CWD: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\GitHub\angular-app

11 silly lifecycle angular-app@0.0.0~app: Args: [ '/d /s /c',

11 silly lifecycle   'composer-rest-server -n carauction-network -p testProfile -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always -P 3000' ]

12 silly lifecycle angular-app@0.0.0~app: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null

13 info lifecycle angular-app@0.0.0~app: Failed to exec app script

14 verbose stack Error: angular-app@0.0.0 app: `composer-rest-server -n carauction-network -p testProfile -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always -P 3000`

14 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477

14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)

14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)

14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)

14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)

14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

15 verbose pkgid angular-app@0.0.0

16 verbose cwd C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\GitHub\angular-app

17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601

18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "app"

19 error node v6.10.0

20 error npm  v3.10.10

21 error code ELIFECYCLE

22 error angular-app@0.0.0 app: `composer-rest-server -n carauction-network -p testProfile -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always -P 3000`

22 error Exit status 3221225477

23 error Failed at the angular-app@0.0.0 app script 'composer-rest-server -n carauction-network -p testProfile -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always -P 3000'.

23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-app package,

23 error not with npm itself.

23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:

23 error     composer-rest-server -n carauction-network -p testProfile -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always -P 3000

23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

23 error     npm bugs angular-app

23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

23 error     npm owner ls angular-app

23 error There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running on Windows -- this is not a supported platform at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. Indeed, I was running it on windows using docker toolbox. When I tried to look into the ledger the asset was added in there. The only problem I think was the event did not work well or I might not have configure it properly.